# What is the maximum cassette teeth for my mt210 3x9 crankset (44/32/22)

Tags: chain, crankset, gears, cassette

I'm currently assembling a bike. I bought a Shimano mt210 3x9 (44/32/22) crankset. I'm wondering what maximum teeth cassette should I buy that will be suitable and compatible with this crankset? Also what chain should I use for a 3x9 setup with my crankset and future cassette

Additional info:
Will also be using a 3x9 m3100 alivio groupset

Thanks in advance for the answers. Ride safe everyone!

Answer (score 7):

36 tooth.

The MT210 is used in a number of series - M3000 and the M4000 series. The RD-M4000 rear derailleur has a 36 tooth limit for its largest sprocket. It also has a capacity of 45 tooth, which means 11-36 cassette on 22-44 chainrings.

These are published maximums, while Shimano is conservative with these numbers, and some people will claim success with larger cassettes, I would not recommend going larger. 36/22 gives a very low gear at which time getting off and walking is often faster, and a larger cassette is likely to cause problems such a spoor shifting and too large jump between gears.

Comment: Being of those who claim to have installed a 42T cassette on a M3000, I confirm the shifting performance is degraded: it was a compromise I did to have a wider range (because I have a double chainring in the front). With such a triple chainring, I certainly don't recommend installing a bigger cassette. It can also make sense to install a 34T cassette: the difference with a 36T won't be noticeable, and you'll stay closer the rated capacity of the derailleur (with a 36T, you'll exceed by 2 teeth).

Comment: It's not just that walking is faster. I used a 22 / 36 ratio on a 27.5" wheel bike and found the ratio to be so low as to be nearly unusable. I found it hard to keep balance and keep the front wheel on the ground. This may not be an issue for a more skilled rider (but then the rider is presumably stronger too?) or for a bike with a different geometry.